# Standalone IntentService error: Unable to start service Intent {act = com.example.. pkg=com.example.somepkg} U=0: not found

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am trying to start a standalone intent service from another android client application, and I cannot for the life of me get it working even after spending hours looking online.

The error is as follows:

> 04-02 16:40:32.052  2131  6557 W ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { act=com.example.zorro.Slash pkg=com.example.cookie } U=0: not found

The apps are as follows:

Intent Class:

```java
package com.example.zorro;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class Slash extends IntentService {
    /**
     * Creates an IntentService.  Invoked by your subclass's constructor.
     *
     * @param name Used to name the worker thread, important only for debugging.
     */
    public Slash(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    private static final String TAG = "ZORRO";
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Hello world from Zorro Service");

    }
}
```

**Intent Service AndroidManifest.xml:**

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.zorro">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <service android:name="com.example.zorro.Slash" android:enabled = "true" android:exported = "true" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Client App Code:**

```java
package com.example.cookie;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        serviceIntent.setAction("com.example.zorro.Slash");
        serviceIntent.setPackage(this.getPackageName());
        startService(serviceIntent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

First from Android Studio I build the intent service and load it to the emulator via the run button. I set the launch options to **Nothing** and the **Deploy** to **Default APK**.

The client application I run on the same emulator from a different android studio instance.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the missing piece was setting the class name on the intent in the client code.

Specifically

```java
serviceIntent.setClassName("com.example.zorro", "com.example.zorro.Slash");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
serviceIntent.setAction("com.example.zorro.Slash");
```

Your `<service>` does not have an `<intent-filter>` with this `<action>`. Hence, Android cannot find the service.

Comment: Even after adding the intent-filter to the AndroidManifest.xml of the service, in the following snippet:
``` xml
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.zorro.Slash" />
            </intent-filter>
```
I get the same result